# How to reuse composable props in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

Essentially, i want to build input fields components (textfeids, textarea, checkbox, ...).
Since they share some attributes ie (id, name,...), my approach was to create a composable and defined the common prop definition and use them in the individual components. However, it seem it does work. Is there a way I can achieve this in vue 3 composable approach. Below is the composable.

```js
// prop definition
import { defineProps } from "vue";

export const useCoreFieldProps = () => {
  const props = defineProps<{
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    required?: boolean;
  }>();

  return {
    props,
  };
};
```

```ts
// composable usage
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useCoreFieldProps } from "@/composables/useFields";

const { props: coreProps } = useCoreFieldProps();

</script>
```

Comment: `defineProps()` is a closure function. Do not put it in other functions.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Did you try just moving to a [setup function](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html), instead of `<script setup>` ? You might be able to just have a separate file with the definition, and then spread it into the props. Not as elegant, but could work.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than calling defineProps in the composable, you can return just the object and you can call defineProps on it in your component:

```
// composable definition

export const useCoreFieldProps = () => {
  const fieldProps = {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    required?: boolean;
  };

  return {
    fieldProps,
  };
};

// composable usage
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useCoreFieldProps } from "@/composables/useFields";

const { fieldProps } = useCoreFieldProps();

defineProps(fieldProps);

// or add your own props or override:
defineProps({
  ...fieldProps,
  maxLength?: string,
  pattern?: string
});

</script>
```

You will unfortunately lose automated documentation of props if you’re using storybook or similar component library browsing tools, but hopefully they'll add support for that soon.

The other option is extends, but the docs don’t really explain how that works in Vue 3 with composition.

Comment: How would I in this case consume `fieldProps` inside the `useCoreFieldProps` composition?

Comment: good point.. that won't work the way i wrote it. you can't call defineProps inside the composable and the standard practice for props in composables is to pass the props in.. so ou might need to separate those two things. for the prop definitions it might make more sense to have an object than a composable

Comment: In fact, that's what I ended up doing... But this is one of the two places where my migration from `vue-property-decorator` to 100% composition API hurts me :)

Comment: How can this work? Some is not valid typescript, e.g. `const?` declarations must have an initializer. `extends` does not work yet, but there is an open issue - see https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4294

Answer (score 0):

Well... not sure if this is conforming to best practices but I'm having a bit of luck by attaching the prop definitions as a property of the exported composeable function. so it's looking like this:

```
function useMyComposeable(props) {
  // do composeable stuff
  return {...myValues}
}

useMyComposeable.props = {
  myProp1: {
    default() {
      return ''
    },
  },
}

export default useMyComposeable
```

and then my vue component is looking sorta like this:

```
{
  props: {
    ...useMyComposeable.props
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {...useMyComposeable(props)}
  },
  // do rest of component stuff
}
```

And it seems to be working alright, although I'm not as excited about the multiple lines needed to get it properly set up in the component.